# PC becomes unresponsive when unplugging USB device

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a Saitek pro flight yoke plugged into a 7-port USB3.0 hub and whenever I unplug the yoke from the hub my computer becomes unresponsive and if I click my mouse I get a strange beep through my headphones, if I restart my PC it is all fine but I really do not want to have to restart my PC every time I unplug this device. How can I fix it?

This is the USB hub [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tendak-Transfer-Charging-Separated-Multifunctional-Black/dp/B00VK9PRIU)

Comment: Have you tried plugging the device directly in to your computer? Hubs can be problematic, and I would suggest the problem centers around that. Send us the model of your hub.

Comment: I have added the hub to the original post, no I have not tried plugging it straight into my PC but the problem didnt exist on my old PC, its only since I've upgraded does it happen

Comment: You should test plugged directly in to the PC. It will probably work fine. I understand what you are saying about when the problem started occurring. For reasons that are not easily explained in a comment, I'm fairly confident the problem is your hub. I'm not sure, though, if it is a bad hub, or an incompatibility between your hub and motherboard.